# Is it possible to do asymptotic analysis of series by computer?

Tags: asymptotics, math-software, maple

It is not difficult to show that
$$
S_m = \sum_{d=1}^m \frac {2^d}{\sqrt{d}} = \frac {2^{m+1}}{\sqrt{m}} (1+O(\log(m)/m)).
$$

But I was wondering if it is possible to do such things using computer? I tried maple's aysmpt function using the following code:

```
f := m -> sum(2^d/sqrt(d), d = 1 .. m);
asympt(f(x), x);
```

It does not work. Does there exist programs that can do such jobs?

---

The correct relative error term is $O(1/m)$. I didn't get this using computer, but numerical computation does hint the correct order.

Comment: Mathematica fails too: unless you consider `-2^(1 + n) LerchPhi[2, 1/2, 1 + n] + PolyLog[1/2, 2]' a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ClementC. Can't Mathematica expand this some properly?

Comment: @tired I tried, but didn't succeed. I am no Mathematica wizard, though.